# HTML5 video - Waiting event not firing

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, webkit, html5-video

I'm messing around with HTML5 videos and custom controls and I'm looking to use the waiting event to ideally display a loading image but just writing to the console will do for now.

**The waiting event**

> Playback has stopped because the next frame is not available, but the
>   user agent expects that frame to become available in due course.

I've set an example up here -> http://jsbin.com/uvipev/2/edit#javascript,html,live

Here's the video code minus the controls:

```
<video controls preload="meta">
   <source src="http://www.tools4movies.com/dvd_catalyst_profile_samples/The%20Amazing%20Spiderman%20tablet.mp4" />
   This is video fallback
</video>
```

And here's my event listener for the waiting event.

```
 var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];   

    video.addEventListener('waiting', function() {
        console.log('waiting');
    }, false);
```

Can anyone see why this isn't running? The waiting event sounds like what I need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you looking to display a waiting image while the video buffers for the first time?  If so, you probably aren't looking for `waiting`.

Take a look at this demo: http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html

If you call `play()` without any preloading, you should see `waiting` fire, even on a cached copy.  If you call `load()` before `play()`, you may never see `waiting` fire, since the next frame could always be available.

The best process would be to display your image, call `load()` and then listen wait for either `canplay` or `canplaythrough`.  At that point, hide your image and kick off `play()`.

**Update**

Looking at the video in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bnickel/zE8F3/ Chrome isn't sending the `waiting` event but is instead sending the `stalled` event shortly after the video freezes up.  You're probably going to need to check how things work on each browser you support.  Bear in mind, players like VideoJS are huge (~142KB) because they deal with a lot of browser inconsistencies.

Comment: No, just when we run out of loaded video and have to stop while we wait for more. Waiting seems like the right choice for that but I'm happy to be proved wrong.

Comment: In that case, waiting makes sense.  Are you sure it's not firing?  The demo report `waiting` for me on Chrome, Safari, and Firefox.

Comment: Yep, no console entry, alert or anything. I'll put a JSFiddle up in the morning.

Comment: Updated answer.  It looks like in this case, Chrome is using the `stalled` event instead.

Comment: You're totally right. This isn't for production, just messing around with it to try and learn more about it (and JavaScript).

Answer (score 4):

There's a good chart here that attempts to document the behavior of different browsers in a "buffer underrun" scenario, which is what I think you're looking for.

https://web.archive.org/web/20130902074352/http://www.longtailvideo.com/html5/buffering/

Unfortunately, the browsers are wildly inconsistent, so while I do believe the "waiting" event is what you want, Chrome doesn't fire it.

I've been experimenting with "guessing" when the player is buffering based on the elapsed time of the video, checking for play/pause/etc. events so that I know when the time *should* be increasing.